# Preauthorisation and maintainability

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, permissions, privacy

I am working on a web application (which happens to have a Java+Spring+postgres backend) and I am  adding permission validation to my services to filter data access.

First, I was thinking about implementing my validations in Java and then annotate my services with something like `org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize` to have my validations invoked.

My main concert is about maintainability. As the project grows in size I have no guarantee that in the future all developers will remember or even care about permission enforcement when they add new features.

I turned to row level security but I have the following architectural problem:

[image]

Although RLS solves my maintainability problem, some of my services trigger asynchronous processes that write to the database but do not yield any session, which in turn yields the  user permissions. This takes me back to preauthorisation and its maintainability problem.

Therefore I was wondering if there are other options besides these ones that I haven't considered yet?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You could add. the information which user caused the change to the data for the asynchonous process, then you could use that information with row level security.

Comment: crossed my mind, but not an option unfortunately. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Either make it an option or do without row level security.

Comment: Hey @JoãoMatos, out of curiosity, what solutions have you put in place to solve your problem ? It's an interesting one that I may also face at some point